# Reading non-utf8 encoded data from a network call in golang

Tags: http, go, character-encoding

I am trying to read bytes from http response body in golang. My problem is that the response body is encoded using ISO-8859-1. I want to read the response body in the same encoding and write the contents to a file in the ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Is there a way using which I can accomplish this? I don't want to convert the data into UTF-8 at all.

Comment: Nothing in Go will convert bytes to utf-8 automatically (or any other encoding for that matter). So you don't have to do anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) is a good read about encoding, which you might benefit from.

You are seemingly assuming Go decodes the raw bytes it receives when it performs a request. It does not.

Take this example:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // We perform a request to a Latin-1 encoded page
    resp, err := http.Get("http://andrew.triumf.ca/multilingual/samples/german.meta.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    //     
    f, err := os.Create("/tmp/latin1")
    defer f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    io.Copy(f, resp.Body)
}
```

In the documentation, you can read that `resp.Body` conforms to the `io.ReadCloser` interface, which allows you to read the raw bytes and stream them to a file.

Once we run this code, this is the output of `file -i /tmp/latin1`:

```
/tmp/latin1: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```